# CallMethodAction: can it be used in WPF?

Tags: wpf

When i use `CallMethodAction` in MVVM-WPF i get this error:

> "CallMethodAction" does not exist in the namespace
> "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions".

knowing that i include the following namespaces in my xaml:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

And if it is for SL only, what is the equivalent in WPF

Comment: Interaction dll's always give a lot of referencing errors, make sure the dll is in your project and should be in the packages folder

Answer (score 3):

`CallMethodAction` is in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions` namespace.

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll` in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I use this is wpf for expression ineractivity

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

make sure to add reference to your project

then I add this to ie a combobox:

```
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            your binding here
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: i replaced  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" by   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"according to an advice in some forum but in both cases same error show up

Comment: are you sure your project has a reference to the dll

Answer (score 0):

This may occur due to the presence of conflicting libraries in the links .dll. Remove unnecessary links from the project. I had these links to Microsoft.Office.Interop.